# Bootstrap autocomplete inside a modal has wrong width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a problem with bootstrap autocomplete / jquery autocomplete.

For an example I assigned it to a field outside and inside a model.

If I click on the field outside of the modal then the autocomplete that opens is the whole width of the field, this is the result i need.
The problem appears in the same situation inside the modal.

If I open modal and click on the field there then the autocomplete that opens is not the whole width of the field. And if i select one of the values then next time autocomplete will be something else.

How can i get autocomplete inside modal to be the whole width of the field as the example outside modal?

Here is an jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rns3hang/181/

And my code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="red,green,blue" />

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield2" value="red,green,blue" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
      autocomplete: {
        source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
        delay: 100
      },
      showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
    });

    $('#tokenfield2').tokenfield({


         autocomplete: {
            source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
            delay: 100
          },
          showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
        });
    });

.ui-autocomplete,
.ui-front {
  z-index: 1059;
}

.ui-autocomplete {

}
```